# OneTimeSetup doesnt seem to be finishing before other tests are ran

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing, testing, mstest

I am currently trying to find an element on the webpage, but am getting an exception that it doesn't exist. I think this is happening, because the webpage doesn't get a change to load all the way before it starts looking for the element. I put a wait in my OneTimeSetUp setup() method, but that doesnt seem to be doing anything... All the tests seem to run before the wait is finished. Does anyone have any suggestions to where I would be able to ensure the webpage is loaded, before continuing on with the tests and trying to find elements?

My Current Setup() method:

```
//Executes before tests start
    //Open Homebanking URL and Login
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var _driver = DriverHelper.Driver;
        var driverHelper = new DriverHelper();
        _driver.Url = driverHelper.homebankingURL;
        driverHelper.maximizeWindow(_driver);

        var loginPage = new HomeBankingLoginPage();

        //Enters login credentials
        loginPage.UserName.SendKeys(usr);
        loginPage.Password.SendKeys(pwrd);
        loginPage.Submit.Click();

        //Lets the webpage load before continuing
        _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

        // Checks to make sure the dashboard loaded
        Assert.IsTrue(driverHelper.IsElementPresent(_driver, By.Id("SvgjsSvg1001")));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `Explicit waits` here  :

> Explicit waits are available to Selenium clients for imperative,
> procedural languages. They allow your code to halt program execution,
> or freeze the thread, until the condition you pass it resolves. The
> condition is called with a certain frequency until the timeout of the
> wait is elapsed. This means that for as long as the condition returns
> a falsy value, it will keep trying and waiting.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement firstResult = wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.Id("SvgjsSvg1001")));
```

and then you can assert as you like.

in case you need [Official reference](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/)

Comment: I just tried that and it still seems like it is bypassing that all together... This seems very strange... I did get a new exception OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable

Comment: Did browser open as usual  ?

Comment: It gave me the data; screen and then it wont load after that, thats when it will eventually throws the exception

Comment: Can I have the URL ?